Garage door rollers off track
The upper most wheel has been out of the track on one side for a while now, but it just recently came out on the other side also.  Now when I try to open the door the first wheel to hit the curve where the track turned from vertical just keeps going up, causing the end of the bracket to hit the sheet rock ceiling and stopping the door.
I didn't think I could get it back in the track without disassembling everything because the wheel that rides in the track needs to go in at an angle, which it can't do once the axle has been slid into the bracket, which holds it square to the track. However, I managed to force them both back into place and thought I had temporarily fixed it, but they popped right out again as soon as I cycled the door.
The questions is, what is the root cause of this?  Misalignment?  I had a repairman come out yesterday and he tried to talk me into all new springs and drums which I could not see a reason for...  Can I somehow adjust things to track straighter to better keep the rollers in their respective tracks?
There is obviously a lot of leverage being applied to the roller bracket which is what is causing the upper wheel to pop out, but I can't figure out why.
I know it's a caveman fix, but a single wheel wouldn't be able to pry the upper wheel out, nor would a shorter bracket be long enough to gouge into the ceiling, so part of me wants to try just cutting the top section of the bracket off.  Before going to something that can't be easily undone though, I'd like to understand what's going on, and why after so many years it just started doing this...  (see photos below)





Springs and drums need replacement once in a while.  ROUGHLY every 5 years.   You could argue 10, 15, 20 ... but if other things have failed, it's likely the springs are past end of life.  We can't diagnose that for you over the internet.  On what basis would you see, or not see, a reason to replace them?   2) If the door is off the tracks it's likely it was hit by a car or some part of the track or door has broken or come loose. If you continue using it you may cause further damage.  This also can only be diagnosed by someone at the site.


If the wheels on both sides have come off the track, the upper door segment is now being supported by the motor shuttle?????  This is dangerous.  Don't stand underneath it.

@jay613, A reason I would see for replacing the springs is if they were broken or worn out.  They are neither... I can disconnect the motor, raise the door a couple feet, and it stays in place so I know they are providing sufficient lifting force.  There is a second wheel on each side supporting the upper panel so it isn't in danger of falling.  It seems to be a leverage problem - like the fore and aft pair of wheels are not in the right location, or spacing is wrong.

Try another repairman. You've got a pro out there who checked it out and you didn't like his answer so you're asking a bunch of people on the internet and posted no pictures or videos.  Yes, something is probably out of alignment, a bent bracket or support.

@JACK, I plan to get a second opinion, just trying to cast a wider net...  (I added photos and made another edit)

@DIY75, what part of the track is adjustable?  Because I don't see any adjustability in the tracks, just a couple limited options to place the wheels in different locations on the bracket.

@DIY75, I don't see any adjustability in the tracks. What adjustment point are you looking at?

It is probably show the pictures are shown, but I would check if the tracks are parallel to the door and plumb to the door  The first/bottom wheel seems to pull away from the door and the track top seems tilted away from the door(probably just the picture).

@crip659, I thought the same thing, but need some help stretching a tape to verify consistent width.  Also, if the rails diverged the second wheel ought to pop out at the same spot, right?  There are definitely some slight angles on the bracketry at the top, maybe I can trial and error it if I square everything up?

@isherwood, I added a photo of the springs, but I'm not sure what it's going to tell you - they're both symmetrically tensioned and intact.  The only thing slightly interesting is they're mounted off center, could that be an issue?  I'm not sure what a picture of the cables would do... there's equal tension on each one, nothing's broken, they just provide the up force and don't have anything to do with levering the wheels out of the tracks do they? it sure seems like a track misalignment problem, and not springs.  But if there's something I can zero in on please let me know.

@DIY75, The only adjustability is the fore and aft depth adjustment of the vertical channels.  I don't think adjusting that would do fix this, and it might make the door fit too tight or leave a gap so I'm hesitant to do anything there...

unbolt the bracket from the door panel, reinstall the wheels into the track and then bolt the bracket back on.

Thanks for the additional photos. Tracks have to be quite far out of whack to result in wheels jumping off them. I'm not sure what's happening here if there isn't a severe spring/cable issue.

Briefly:
Where the low-clearance bracket is attached to the door requires steel reinforcement of the door and perfect alignment with with no rotation or twist relative to the track.  Without reinforcement the arm works its way out of alignment, amplifies the resultant twisting forces and self-destructs.
In more detail:
It would be better if I could observe and play with the door, and an experienced installer should have done that whether or not they thought you need new springs.  With that caveat, I'm going to take a guess at what is wrong.
The long metal arm at the top of your door is a "low clearance" arm.  It forces the top panel of the door to run along the track instead of a few inches above it.
It's a lever, like a see-saw, where the wheel in the middle is the pivot, and the hinge on the door and far wheel are at the two ends. It's sensitive to the correct alignment of the bracket attached to the door.  I can see yours has been twisted and mangled.  That is probably a symptom of the same problem.  The hinge in that bracket has to be perfectly perpendicular to the rail in both other axes.  If it is slightly twisted or rotated, that will create a force through the length of the long arm that will twist or rotate the far wheel out of the track.
I think that is what happened, and that force both popped out the wheel and mangled the bracket.
The underlying cause, I am guessing is that the bracket is installed directly to the door without any steel reinforcement along either the top or side of the door.  The door itself can't handle the extra force of the levered arm, so the bracket worked loose, became out of alignment, and twisted itself out of the track.

This is not a great design because the flat side of the track is not really designed to keep rollers captive against that kind of motion.
But most likely, it's the rollers wearing out and getting floppy.  The roller should be very rigid and have no wobble.  That's suggested to me by how easy you got the roller in and out of the track.  Normally you have to bend the track (the flat side of the track not the curved side).
That's a pretty easy fix, those rollers cost $5.
Note the bottom rollers are fairly perilous to swap.  You really need to know what you're doing.  It helps to have the garage door in the entirely "up" position so the spring tension is unwound, and put a vice grip or a bolt through the track to pin the door so it can't roll downward.
